# Did Android 5.0 change the result of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

```
Intent captureImageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(captureImageIntent, TAKE_FIRST_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

In onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

```
String mediaKey = "data";
case TAKE_FIRST_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
   mImageUri1 = data.getData();

   if (mImageUri1 != null) {
       mImageBitmap1 =  (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get(mediaKey);
                    postCaptureImg1();
   } else {
       LOGD(TAG, "mImageUri1 == null");
   }
break;
```

The code works fine on Android version < 5.0. However, on 5.0, it no longer works, mImageUri1 is always null.

Anything changed in Android 5.0 that causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code works fine on Android version < 5.0

No, it does not. It *happened* to work in your limited testing because the particular camera app you used *happened* to return a `Uri` (presumably, the value you supplied via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`). However, there is nothing in [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) that requires camera apps to return a `Uri`. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands of camera apps, both pre-installed ones and ones installed from public channels like the Play Store. Do not rely upon getting a `Uri` back in `onActivityResult()`.

> Anything changed in Android 5.0 that causes this?

Perhaps the camera app that you are using changed to no longer package the `Uri` in the result. This is perfectly legitimate, per the documented protocol.

Comment: After adding extra_output Uri string, Android 5.0 device (Moto E) still does not store the captured image to the Uri in EXTRA_OUTPUT field. It ignored the passed in Uri string and stored the image in some other place. How get I get the uri that is used by the camera app to store the image?

Comment: @windchime: If I had to guess, probably you can't. This is one of the risks of relying upon third-party apps for taking pictures -- not everybody tests their `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementation. The camera app on your Moto E is not the first to have this sort of problem, and it probably won't be the last. All that being said, you could grab the extras `Bundle` from the `Intent` and dump all its contents to LogCat, to see if they happen to put the `Uri` in some non-traditional location. But I am not hopeful.